# Making cross reference to nested enumerated item show periods and parentheses

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I want my references to nested items in an `enumerate`d list to include all the punctuation that was in the list. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item whatever
    \item 1st level \label{first}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item whatever
            \item 2nd level \label{second}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item whatever
                    \item 3rd \label{third} 
                        \begin{enumerate}
                            \item whatever
                            \item 4th \label{fourth}
                        \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

1st: \ref{first}

2nd: \ref{second}

3rd: \ref{third}

4th: \ref{fourth}

\end{document}
```

This is the output I get (I'm showing it as code because the quotes don't preserve spaces at the start of the line)

```
1. whatever  
2. 1st level  

    (a) whatever 

    (b) 2nd level  

        i. whatever  

       ii. 3rd  

            A. whatever  

            B. 4th

1st: 2  
2nd: 2b  
3rd: 2(b)ii  
4th: 2(b)iiB
```

The problem is the missing punctuation in the four references at the end. I want the references at the end to look like this:

> 1st: 2.
>   2nd: 2.(b)
>   3rd: 2.(b).ii.
>   4th: 2.(b).ii.B.

Although admittedly ugly, someone is demanding the references look exactly like they do in the list.

I would prefer to do this without any `\usepackage` stuff that's not standard in most latex installations. So, I want to redefine the way the `\ref` works and have it leave all the punctuation in place, or redefine whatever will make it do what I want, without including any outside package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should there be a dot between "(b)" and "ii" in the third cross-reference?

Comment: Ooops, didn't want that dot between "(b)" and "ii".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any packages as wanted by OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\roman{enumiii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\Alph{enumiv}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\theenumiv}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii.}  %% if you don't want that dot between "(b)" and "ii" remove the . at the end after \theenumii
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item whatever
    \item 1st level \label{first}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item whatever
            \item 2nd level \label{second}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item whatever
                    \item 3rd \label{third}
                        \begin{enumerate}
                            \item whatever
                            \item 4th \label{fourth}
                        \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

1st: \ref{first}

2nd: \ref{second}

3rd: \ref{third}

4th: \ref{fourth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works. I removed the extra dot. Thanks for making it easy with the comment.

Comment: Ciao Harish. How are you?

Comment: @karlkoeller Hi Karl! I am fine but missing you a lot! `:-)`

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to do this using extra packages? I like to keep my preamble clean.